# Compare window.innerWidth using ie/else if

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have created `if/else if` conditions that should check the `window.innerWidth` and update a variable. However it's not detecting screen sizes lower than 768.

What have I done wrong? What could I do to make it better, or more efficient, or cleaner?

```js
var ww = window.innerWidth;
var responsiveScale;

if (ww <= 768) {
  responsiveScale = 1,
    console.log("less than or equal to 768");
} else if (ww > 768 && ww <= 1280) {
  responsiveScale = 2,
    console.log("screen is greater than 768 but less than or equal to 1280");
} else if (ww > 1280 && ww <= 1440) {
  responsiveScale = 3
  console.log("screen is greater than 1280 but less than or equal to 1440");
} else if (ww > 1440 && ww <= 1920) {
  responsiveScale = 4
  console.log("Screen is greater than 1440 but less than or equal to 1920");
} else {
  responsiveScale = 5
  console.log("Screen is greater 1920");
}
```

Comment: The snippet prints `less than or equal to 768` for me.

Comment: @iota It does, but its not changing as you resize the window. Try it in the "Expand Snippet" window.

Comment: Why would it? It's only run once. If there's more context to the code it needs to be included in the question.

Comment: Are you re-running the function every time the window resizes?

Comment: Yes, I have it reload using: window.onresize = function(){ location.reload(); }

Answer (score 1):

You should to listen for window resize events using

```
window.onresize = function() {
//compute the window innerWidth here
}
```